# HTML being appended as text not html

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is outputting text in the browser and not html markup.  The my_detail element is on the page from server side render, and i'm trying to append some other html via GTM.javascript.  Having a brain fart, please assist

```
var $testString = "<h1 class='testing123'>asdasd asd</h1>"
$("#my_detail").append($testString)
```

Comment: @Hodrobond this is the question, not an answer ;)

Comment: Apologies, I appear to be misunderstanding. [This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8zh0kLpp/) is a copy paste of your code and renders the `<h1>` tag appropriately on my screen, and I thought there was some issue where yours was explicitly displaying `<h1 class='testing123'>asdasd asd</h1>` instead of `asdasd asd`

Comment: Why are you calling `.html()`? That will return the HTML markup.

Comment: @Barmar sorry that was just an error  i was playing around debugging, wasn't actually calling like that.

Comment: You need to provide an MCVE that demonstrates the problem. The code you posted should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to append some HTML, you have to define it as HTML, not as a string.

So this will work:

```
var testHTML = $("<h1>").attr("class","testing123").text("asdasd asd");
$("#my_detail").append(testHTML);
```

Answer (score 2):

**1st:** If you need to append the `html` variable your updated code should work because *.append() will parse its argument as HTML*

```js
var $testString = "<h1 class='testing123'>asdasd asd</h1>"
$("#my_detail").append($testString);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="my_detail"></div>
```

**2nd:** If you need to render the `html` string as a code?? .. so you need to wrap your code in `<xmp>`

```js
var $testString = "<h1 class='testing123'>asdasd asd</h1>"
$("#my_detail").append('<xmp>' + $testString + '</xmp>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="my_detail"></div>
```

Comment: This isn't necessary. `.append()` will parse its argument as HTML.